# How to detect an server IP from client and connect with that server using TCP/IP?

Tags: networking

i have a three system connected in a LAN and one of the system has server program running but the client doesnt know IP of that server. Client has to detect that server and connect with that server . Is it possible to do and whether it can be done using TCP/IP

Answer (score 0):

You could probably send a TCP package to the broadcast address of your network when trying to find the servers ip address.
That way every device in your network receives your package. Then just make the server listen and respond to that package. That way you can easily find your servers IP address without trying to connect to every single IP